# FP growth model in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to run FP growth algorithm in spark using following  code using spark 2.2 MLlib :

```
val fpgrowth = new FPGrowth()
  .setItemsCol("items")
  .setMinSupport(0.5)
  .setMinConfidence(0.6)
val model = fpgrowth.fit(dataset1)
```

Where `dataset` is being pulled from a SQL code:

```
select items from MLtable
```

the output for `items` column in this table looks like this:

```
"NFL Cricket MLB Unknown1 Unknown2 Unknown Unknown Unknown",
"Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown CCC DDD RRR",
"Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown CFB Unknown Unknown Unknown",
"Unknown Cricket Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown",
"NFL Unknown MLB NBA CFB Unknown Unknown Unknown"
```

Whenever I try to run my ML model I run into following error:

> Items in a transaction must be unique but got WrappedArray

I tried to play around with this multiple times but ran into error. Would really appreciate any help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message tells you, *items in a transaction must be unique*:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{split, udf}

val df = Seq(
  "NFL Cricket MLB Unknown1 Unknown2 Unknown Unknown Unknown",
  "Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown CCC DDD RRR",
  "Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown CFB Unknown Unknown Unknown",
  "Unknown Cricket Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown Unknown",
  "NFL Unknown MLB NBA CFB Unknown Unknown Unknown"
).toDF("items")

val distinct = udf((xs: Seq[String]) => xs.distinct)

val items = df
  .withColumn("items", split($"items", "\\s+"))
  // Keep only distinct values
  .withColumn("items", distinct($"items"))


new FPGrowth().fit(items).freqItemsets.show
// +-------------------+----+
// |              items|freq|
// +-------------------+----+
// |              [MLB]|   2|
// |         [MLB, NFL]|   2|
// |[MLB, NFL, Unknown]|   2|
// |     [MLB, Unknown]|   2|
// |          [Unknown]|   5|
// |              [NFL]|   2|
// |     [NFL, Unknown]|   2|
// |          [Cricket]|   2|
// | [Cricket, Unknown]|   2|
// |              [CFB]|   2|
// |     [CFB, Unknown]|   2|
// +-------------------+----+
```